How do I pin an action to a specific SHA?
A warning is appearing in my IDE indicating that my action should be pinned to a specific SHA. I understand SHAs from Git commits, but how do I track down the SHA for GitHub Actions?
Fake Example: mycoderepo/mylibrary-action@v2
Real Example: github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v3
This is what I found on GitHub regarding the secure use of third-party actions:

Pin actions to a full length commit SHA
Pinning an action to a full length commit SHA is currently the only way to use an action as an immutable release. Pinning to a particular SHA helps mitigate the risk of a bad actor adding a backdoor to the action's repository, as they would need to generate a SHA-1 collision for a valid Git object payload. When selecting a SHA, you should verify it is from the action's repository and not a repository fork.


GitHub actions are pointers to GitHub repos, with commits in them, e.g. from your real example: https://github.com/github/codeql-action

I appreciate that feedback. And your link makes sense to me. But I remain curious how you find the link to a repo (to get the SHA) for a random Action necessary to support your build? For instance, how so I find the SHA for the latest version of actions/checkout@v3?

The other ask, if someone knows the answer, can they use @BMitch's example for that Action and post an answer with the syntax for pinning to a specific SHA?  Thank you!

How you get the link to the repo?! An action name is the repo, read e.g.https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses

The action name is simply a pointer to a GitHub repository under a GitHub organization. The first part of the name before / is the organization, whereas the second part is the repo:

actions/checkout@v3 is located at https://github.com/actions/checkout (user: actions, repo: checkout)

Longer paths represent folders inside the repo:

github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v3 is located at https://github.com/github/codeql-action/blob/main/upload-sarif/

The remaining portion of the name prefixed by a @ represents the commit identifier. It is generally in the form of a tag @v3 but it could also be a specific SHA:

actions/checkout@f43a0e5ff2bd294095638e18286ca9a3d1956744

In fact, a tag is simply a pointer to a specific SHA:

actions/checkout@v3 points to actions/checkout@f43a0e5ff2bd294095638e18286ca9a3d1956744

To detect the specific SHA, you simply need to:

Determine the appropriate repo name, from the action (as explained above)
Visit the repo on GitHub
Click on the branch/tag switcher to locate the tag you are interested in
Copy the short (or full) SHA from the referenced commit



